# Problem from Evans PDE on $u$ and $v$ satisfying $u_t+u_x=d(v-u)$ and $v_t-v_x=d(u-v)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This is problem 22 p. 89 from chapter 2 of the book *Partial Differential Equations* by Lawrence C. Evans (2nd ed., 2010).

> Let $u$ denote the density of particles moving to the right with speed one along the real line and let $v$ denote the density of particles moving to the left with speed one. If at rate $d>0$ right-moving particles randomly become left-moving, and vice versa, we have the system of PDE
>   $$\left \{
>  \begin{aligned}
>   u_t+u_x &= d(v-u)  \\
>   v_t-v_x &= d(u-v) .
>  \end{aligned} \right.$$
>   Show that both $w:=u$ and $w:=v$ solve the telegraph equation
>   $$w_{tt}+2dw_t-w_{xx}=0 .$$

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $w := u$, use the first equation to get

$v = u + \frac{u_t+u_x}{d}$

Put this into the second equation to get

$$\left( u + \frac{u_t+u_x}{d}\right)_t -\left( u + \frac{u_t+u_x}{d}\right)_x = d \left( u - (u + \frac{u_t+u_x}{d}) \right) $$

This simplify to

$$u_t + \frac{u_{tt}+u_{xt}}{d} -u_x - \frac{u_{xt}+u_{xx}}{d}= -u_t-u_x $$

And if you multiply this by $d$ you get the result :

$$u_{tt}+2d u_t - u_{xx} = 0$$

For $w := v$, it's the same idea